# Is it possible to turn off the trackpad low battery notification?

Tags: trackpad, magic-trackpad

Generally speaking I like to change the battery once the battery is completely used up, but the system will kept notifying me once the percentage dropped below 20%. Is there a way to turn it off (or make the notification only comes up once it dropped below 5%)?

Comment: would this work for you http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/57427/46541

Comment: @Buscar웃 no it doesn't turn off the alerts. It just replaces the icons.

Comment: That alert is probably there for the Lion batteries which should not be discharged below 20%. I do not know how to turn it off.

Comment: It is a very annoying alert... My batteries still work for weeks past the 20% mark. Here's hoping Apple will allow us to disable it in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't mind the alert or warning, but I do mind the weeks of having a blinking icon in my Menubar.  Here's what I did in Terminal:
>
> ```
> $ cd /System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/Bluetooth.menu/Contents/Resources/
> $ sudo cp lowbatt.pdf lowbatt.backup.pdf
> $ sudo cp BlueTooth_Connected.pdf lowbatt.pdf
> ```
>
> This replaces the low battery icon with the same connected icon.  I assume the icon is still "blinking" in that it's switching one for the other, but since they're now the same, you don't notice.
>
> Now I get the 20%, 10%, 5% alerts, but no annoying blink.
>
> This is in Lion.  It's likely that system updates and perhaps even Mountain Lion will undo this, but it can probably be reapplied after updates are performed.
>
> ---
>
> For Mountain Lion, the relevant files are named:
>
> - `Bluetooth_Low_Battery.pdf`
> - `Bluetooth_Connected.pdf`

[How can you disable the low battery warnings for bluetooth devices?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28268/how-can-you-disable-the-low-battery-warnings-for-bluetooth-devices/57427#57427) by [seanhussey](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9255/seanhussey)