# Disable battery warning for bluetooth keyboard and mouse

Tags: keyboard, battery, bluetooth, mouse, notifications

I would like to disable the extremely annoying notification popups when my bluetooth mouse or keyboards batteries are getting low. I have enough rechargeable batteries in my drawer, so I do not need a prior notification.

Basically my problem is similar to this older [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28268/how-can-you-disable-the-low-battery-warnings-for-bluetooth-devices), but in newer OS versions, the notification center is being used instead of a blinking bluetooth icon.

I've already checked Notification Center's preferences, but could not find any entry to disable the battery warnings. The Keyboard and Mouse settings do not seem provide any options either.

To clarify: I **never** want to see this part again:

[image: Battery notification]

(image from [here](http://www.macworld.com/article/3024515/macs/how-to-disable-mouse-and-keyboard-low-battery-warnings-you-cant.html))

**[edit 2018-10-20]** I just returned from vacation and had an email notification about an answer here (the email preview suggest to unload a Launch Agent). The answer got deleted in the meantime, so I assume this would have some unexpected side effects? I’d still be glad about a quick feedback by the answer’s author, why it didn’t work as expected.

Comment: So - you're saying if we can't stop the alert entirely, let the alerts fire but see if we can prevent Notification Center from that portion of the alerting?

Comment: Not sure whether I understand you correctly, but I've edited my original question.

Comment: Apparently there is no way to do this currently: http://www.macworld.com/article/3024515/macs/how-to-disable-mouse-and-keyboard-low-battery-warnings-you-cant.html

Comment: Who ever invented these "low battery" warnings over at Apple should be shot and their ashes scattered to the four winds. My batteries have been showing as "low" for months now and the keyboard is still working.

Comment: Agree, that's just a shame from Apple.

Comment: I get my keyboard warning at 18% level on batteries. That's maybe months left. It seems you could at least change the threshold for the warnings to start.